# Increase Postgrex database timeout during CircleCI tests

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto, circleci

I'm running into an issue where `mix test` is sporadically failing on CircleCI with the following error:

> 16:46:05.935 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.9303.0>) disconnected: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) owner #PID<0.73.0> timed out because it owned the connection for longer than 15000ms

I tried increasing the timeout in my test config to this:

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  database: System.get_env("DB_NAME"),
  username: System.get_env("DB_USER"),
  password: System.get_env("DB_PASS"),
  hostname: System.get_env("DB_HOST"),
  pool: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox,
  timeout: 30000
```

But it's still timing out after 15000ms with this in place. Is there another setting I should be looking for?

Comment: Could you try setting `ownership_timeout: 30_000` as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to increase the `ownership_timeout` here, not `timeout`. This is documented in the module doc of [`Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.html) under the section `owner timed out because it owned the connection for longer than Nms`:

> If you have a long running test (or you’re debugging with `IEx.pry`), the timeout for the connection ownership may be too short. You can increase the timeout by setting the `:ownership_timeout` options for your repo config in `config/config.exs` (or preferably in `config/test.exs`):